# compare unique buyers for each store in its first 30 days of opening? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, partitioning

i have two tables
shopper :

| shopper_id | date | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-12-02 | 4321 |

and store:

| store_id | opening_date |
| --- | --- |
| 4321 | 2021-11-23 |

i want to get the total number of unique shoppers who visited each store within the first 30 days of opening.

so far  have

```
SELECT
    store_id,
    opening_date,
    COUNT( shopper_id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY opening_date )

FROM
    store AS s
    INNER JOIN shoppers AS sp ON s.store_id = sp.store_id

WHERE
    opening_date <= opening_date + 30
```

Comment: `opening_date <= opening_date + 30` <-- I think you typo'd something here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
SELECT store.store_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(shopper_id)) as visitor_count
FROM store LEFT JOIN shopper ON store.store_id = shopper.store_id
  AND store.opening_date <= shopper.date
  AND shopper.date <= store.opening_date + interval '30 days'
GROUP BY store.store_id;
```

See this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bxKrVFqeFLSy6uzySgppVk/0) for better understanding.